# regex replace just a part in gedit

Tags: regex, gedit

I have some text containing `.  A....`
The regex is `[.][\s][\s][!A-Z]`
This finds the containing string. The problem is, that I don't know how to replace all of it with `\n` except the `[A-Z]`

Comment: Just as a side-note `[]` is not necessary around `\s`. Also, `[.]` can be rewritten as `\.`. So `\.\s\s[!A-Z]` is the same as your original regex (but shorter). Also, instead of declaring `\s\s`, use `\s{2}`. It uses 1 less step (at the expense of 1 extra character). Also, you can use grundic's solution or `\.\s{2}(?=[!A-Z])` and simply replace with `\n`. This option doesn't store a grouping into memory, but rather the position (it should perform slightly faster)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [grouping](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) and back refer to them by `\1`, `\2`, etc.

Change your regex to `[.][\s][\s]([!A-Z])` and replace it with `\n\1`